# Bean SpringTemplateEngine not found error after externalizing spring property file

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Bean SpringTemplateEngine not found error after externalizing spring property file

to solve this,Have tried to define bean in Application class.But getting error as- Two bean found with same name.

Comment: this error is all about conflicting bean.. try to create two different bean/object with same name/id of a class.. please check your bean creation configuration..

Comment: I am using spring boot auto configuration when i have externalized the property file and deployed the war. it is saying SpringTemplateEngine Bean not found. To solve this i have defined the bean in the Application Class .Then i am getting the error Two bean found with same name.@VikrantKashyap